# If else statement complications, coding challenge : Ruby

Tags: ruby

Working on a task to return true if a triangle can be built with the sides of given length and false in any other case.

Currently this is what my solution looks like:

```
def isTriangle(a,b,c)
  if a > b and c 
    return false 
  else a < b and c
    return true 
  end
end
```

and this is what it's outputting:

```
Expected: false, instead got: true
Expected: false, instead got: true
Test Passed: Value == false
Test Passed: Value == false
Expected: false, instead got: true
Expected: false, instead got: true
```

When I print a it returns two values, 1 and 7. Arguments b = 2, and c = 2. I'm not sure how to write an expression that seperates the two values assigned to a? what would you recommend?

Please find a link to the kata [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56606694ec01347ce800001b/train/ruby)

Comment: It is completely unclear what your code is trying to do. It is also very hard to read, the indentation is all over the place. In your code, it looks like `a` and `b` are `Comparable` objects and `c` is a boolean value, is that correct?

Comment: sorry wrote this pretty late and out of frustration.

Comment: FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done a bit of digging I thought it may be worth sharing. With triangle inequality the sum of the lengths of any two sides must be greater than or equal to the length of the remaining side for it to be classed a triangle.

Taking that logic we can write:

```
def is_triangle(a,b,c)
 a,b,c = [a, b, c].sort # returns => 1, 2, 2 and => 2, 2, 7
 a + b > c # => 1, 2, 2 returns true, 2, 2, 7 returns false
end
```

Comment: take the running time and computational resources into consideration too. you would see why `(a + b > c) && (a + c > b) && (b + c > a)` is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_triangle(a,b,c)
   (a + b > c) && (a + c > b) && (b + c > a)
end
```

Ruby the solution:

Comment: What I meant was that you could replace the single line of your method with `(a + b > c) && (a + c > b) && (b + c > a)`. Nothing else. That's because this expression already returns `true` or `false`. Remember, a method returns the last value that is computed, here `true` or `false`.

Comment: Just `((a + b > c) && (a + c > b) && (b + c > a))` is enough as the statement return boolean value no need of `? true : false`